# How do you redirect audio output in FreeRDP?

Tags: audio, freerdp

I have trouble redirecting audio during my rdp connection with freerdp.

When I use this command:

```
xfreerdp /v:ServerName /u:User /p:Password /d:Domain /audio
```

I get this error:

```
Warning rdpsnd_process_connect (/home/USER/Desktop/FreeRDP-master/FreeRDP/channels/rdpsnd/client/rdpsnd_main.c:801): no sound device.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `/audio`, try to pass `/sound`:

```
xfreerdp /u:dinosaur /d:cretaceous /sound /v:pangaea.ancient.int
```